# Reading/Writing set of records in different go routines - what datastructure to use

Tags: go, data-structures, slice

I have a chat application using 2 go routines. I would like to add/remove records to/from the list in one thread and read the same list from the other thread.

As I am pretty new in Go, I am a bit puzzled about what data structure should be used. I thought of slices, but not sure that I use it the right way

```
func listener(addr *net.UDPAddr, clients *[] *net.UDPAddr, messages chan clientMessage) {

    for {
            *clients=append(*clients,otherAddr)     
    }
}

func sender(messages chan clientMessage,clients *[] *net.UDPAddr) {

  for {
    message :=<- messages
    for _,client := range *clients {
            fmt.Printf("Message %s sent to %s\n", message.message, client.String())

    }
  }
}


func main() {   
    var clients [] *net.UDPAddr
    go listener(s,&clients,messageCh)
    go sender(messageCh,&clients) 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since listener only needs to write, and sender only needs to read - this is a good example of using channels to communicate. The flow would look like the following:

1. Listener would post the new client to the channel.
2. Sender will receive the new client and will update its local slice
   of clients.

It will be a lot cleaner and safer this way - since listener will not be able to "accidentally" read and sender will not be able to "accidentally" write. Listener can also close the channel to indicate to the sender that it's done.

Answer (score 2):

A slice is looks OK for the scenario, but a [mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) is needed to prevent concurrent read and write to the slice.

Let's bundle the slice and mutex together in a struct and add methods for the two operations: add and enumerate.

```
type clients struct {
    mu     sync.Mutex
    values []*net.UDPAddr
}

// add adds a new client
func (c *clients) add(value *net.UDPAddr) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    c.values = append(c.values, value)
    c.mu.Unlock()
}

// do calls fn for each client
func (c *clients) do(fn func(*net.UDPAddr) error) error {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    for _, value := range c.values {
        if err := fn(value); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func listener(addr *net.UDPAddr, clients *clients, messages chan clientMessage) {
    for {
        clients.add(otherAddr)
    }
}

func sender(messages chan clientMessage, clients *clients) {

    for {
        message := <-messages
        clients.do(func(client *net.UDPAddr) error {
            fmt.Printf("Message %s sent to %s\n", message.message, client.String())
            return nil
        })
    }
}

func main() {
    var clients clients
    go listener(s, &clients, messageCh)
    go sender(messageCh, &clients)
}
```